# Can someone explain why my Python list index is coming up the same for different index's

Tags: python, arrays, string, uppercase

So I'm learning on code wars at the moment and have been at this problem for over an hour... what seems like a simple task is taking me forever to figure out. anyways here is the snippet of where I'm struck.
I want to return a list of index's for an array of string characters, but only if the character is uppercase. This works fine for different letters, but when two of the same character appear they return the same index. Ex. 'abCdeC' index returned is [2],[2]

```
def solution(s):
    arry = list(s)
    for x in arry:
        if x.isupper():
            print(arry.index(x))
solution('breakCamelBamp')
print('  spacer  ')
solution('breakCamelCamp')
```

Comment: It finds the first index of x.

Comment: See the documentation of the method `index`. It returns the index of the first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks ill look for a method that doesn't return the first occurrence.

Comment: @RonH86 You're not going to find a function that automatically returns the "right" index. You need to keep track of the index.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the problem is with `index` always returning the index of the first occurrence. Instead, try iterating with the current index:

```
def solution(s):
    arry = list(s)
    for i, x in enumerate(arry):
        if x.isupper():
            print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Index returns the first occurrence. You can use counter instead:

```
def solution(s):
    arry = list(s)
    count_array = []
    count = 0
    for x in arry:
        if x.isupper():
            count_array.append(count)
        count += 1
    print(count_array)

solution('breakCamelBamp')
print('  spacer  ')
solution('breakCamelCamp')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help that's all i needed to make the rest of my solution work.